# $ \frac{1}{t_n} \int_0^{t_n} e^{2 \pi i h f(x)} \, dx \to 0$ if $ \frac{1}{n} \int_0^n e^{2 \pi i h f(x)} \, dx \to 0 $

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose that $f$ is a measurable functions on the real line and $h \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{ 0 \}$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{n} \int_0^n e^{2 \pi i h f(x)} \, dx \to 0
$$
as $n \in \mathbb N$ tends to infinity. I want to show that if $(t_n)_n$ is an arbitrary sequence tending to infinity then also
$$
\frac{1}{t_n} \int_0^{t_n} e^{2 \pi i h f(x)} \, dx \to 0.
$$
I read this in a paper without proof. Right now I don't see how to approach this problem. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Hint: any $t_n$ lies between two integers.

Comment: But couldn't it be still big although the quantity at the integers is small?